# n-dimentional integral over Multivariate Gaussian

Tags: discrete-signals, gaussian, integration, probability-distribution-function

given the prior distribution of $\mathbf{a}=[a_1,\ldots,a_K]^T$ as
\begin{equation}
p_{\mathbf{a}}(\mathbf{a})= \frac{1}{\pi^K \det{\mathbf{R_{\mathbf{a}}}}} e^{\mathbf{a}^H \mathbf{R}_{\mathbf{a}}^{-1} \mathbf{a}}
\end{equation}
I am looking into  the expectation of a  exponential function of a nonlinear function of $\mathbf{a}$ as

\begin{equation}
E_{\mathbf{a}}\{e^{\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{z}+\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{R}_{n}^{-1}\mathbf{a}}\}=c_1\int_{\mathbf{a}} e^{\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{z}+\mathbf{z}^H\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{R}_{n}^{-1}\mathbf{a}} p_{\mathbf{a}}(\mathbf{a}) d\mathbf{a}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{R}_a$ and $\mathbf{R}_n$ are covariance matrices and therefore  positive definite. Is there any way to compute this integral?

Comment: How is this related to signal processing? It may be a better fit in one of the math-oriented SE sites.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{z}$? What is $\mathbf{R}_n$ and is it different from $\mathbf{R}_a$? You may want to check [Inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: $\mathbf{R}_a$ and $\mathbf{R}_n$ are covariance matrices and therefore  positive definite.